# didUpdateUserLocation not called in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation, userlocation

Since I updated to iOS SDK 8 and 8.1, there have been many problems, including that the method of CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations is no longer called.

Here the code:
 In viewDidLoad:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

The method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{ NSLog(@"Call?"); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Are you testing this on simulator or on device? You must test this on actual device. FWIW, `didUpdateLocations` works fine on my iOS 8.1 device.
2. Make sure that you specified the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` string or else the app won't present the authorization message, and you won't be authorized.

   Obviously, if you don't *need* "always usage", you should just `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and then you must specify `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` string.
3. Have you checked `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`? I do that before I even try to authorize or start location services, because if it's either `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`, the location services won't work until the user goes to settings and remedies that. You may want to present them a message to that effect if you get either of these authorization codes.
4. Have you implemented `locationManager:didFailWithError:`? Does it report anything?
5. Have you implemented `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`? Are you getting this called with a successful authorization status?

Answer (score 2):

Need include `MapKit.framework` from `Capabilities`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and my code (viewdidupdate method) was missing this:

_mapView.delegate = self;

For some reason the app worked in ios 7 without the line, but in ios 8.1 didUpdateUserLocation was never called.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. Forgetting to set the delegate is a very common problem.

Comment: That did it for me! The mapVIEW receives the events, so you should implement its delegate, makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Specify **both** NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in your plist:

[image]

Also in code, request authorization:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) { // or requestAlwaysAuthorization
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; // or requestAlwaysAuthorization
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```